# Is there a way to know the limit of notification on every Android devices?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I encountered this issue on Xiaomi devices, is there a way to know the limit of notification on every devices?

```
*Package has already posted or enqueued 25 notifications.  Not showing more.*
```

I tried finding a documentation about it, but it seems there's no any of it.

Comment: just don't spam, or make your code group notifications and update already posted ones

Comment: But is there also a way to get that error/response that I posted to my application?

Comment: Not unless rooted, otherwise all spammy apps would keep spamming but keep it below the limit. Also your notifications can be muted by user too and you cannot do much about that. So knowing such limit exist and knowing you are affected, rething your code to make it more user friendly. I am unable to tell what is the use case you need more that 25 notifications. It won't even fit the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR; I really suggest you rethink your notification strategy. If user did not read previous 25 notifications yet, showing 26th adds no value and makes no much of an impact.

---

Do you **really** need to post that many notifications? Maybe, but for now, my answer is "not really". If you make so much noise, no matter what's notification is about and how important it is, it will be lost in that crowd. So if your app needs to really tell user that much, you should keep the track of notification details within your app, having i.e. dedicated activity with list of all the these information where user can enter either from within the app and by taping the notification (that also makes it "immune" to notification mute that user can set for your app) and then post system notification only once, with summary message like "you have XX events to review.. whatever". Then, as time goes and there's more to tell the user, just update that notification to your liking. It still fine to even post 2nd notification for more important stuff (btw: check notification channels and priority) if that'd make sense for you, but again, stay as low with notification number as you can. That way user can still see all these info w/o suffering from notification shade being overcrowded.